# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable , while accessing instance and class variable

Tags: python

```
class test(object):
    class_var=5
    def __init__(self):
        self.abc=9

obj=test()
print("Instance Variable")
print obj.abc()
print("Class Variable")
print test.class_var()
print("Class variable through Instance Variable")
print obj.class_var()
test.class_var=99
print("After Changing")
print("Class Variable")
print test.class_var()
print("Class variable through Instance Variable")
print obj.class_var()
```

I am relatively new to python, and i was checking how the Class Variables and instance variables workin python and how they are similar to the static variables in java and c++. I tried executing this code and i got this error

> F:\pythont>python static.py Instance Variable Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "static.py", line 8, in 
>       print obj.abc() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>
> F:\pythont>

I am pretty much confused because i am pretty sure the variables are accessible in python without the use of getters. Since other small programs work when i directly access :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `obj.abc` is an integer.  When you put parentheses after it, you are attempting to call it, but you can't call an integer.

To read the variable value, just use `obj.abc`, without parentheses.

Comment: Aah, damn beginners mistake i guess. I really didnt see through it. Cant i delete this question now. 
Feeling ashamed, :\

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri: Just leave it, it can help others who have similar problems and search for answers.